# Funding foreign asset purchase with repo

Tags: fx, trading, swaps, repo, money-markets

https://www.bis.org/publ/qtrpdf/r_qt1709e.pdf

extract from page 38

> An investor wants to buy a foreign currency security with domestic
> cash but does not wish to run FX risk. Then, three transactions are
> equivalent. The agent may:
>
> 1. combine a spot and forward FX deal, ie buy the required FX spot, purchase the security and sell the same amount of FX forward;
> 2. use an FX swap, ie swap the domestic currency for the foreign currency and purchase the security;
> 3. **keep the domestic cash and finance the security by borrowing in the foreign repo market, incurring outright debt.**

I am a little confused about strategy 3, does it mean you lend your local ccy cash in exchange for the foreign security or something else?

Answer (score 3):

It means:  purchase the foreign asset and simultaneously use this asset as collateral to borrow money in the same currency.  For example, you are a USD investor.  You buy a Japanese Government bond for Yen 1bn, and you enter a repo where you borrow Yen 1bn by pledging the JGB as collateral.  By doing this, you have no FX risk.

Comment: step by step, do you mean this?  1) US investor exchanges USD for JPY at spot rate 2) uses the yen amount to buy a JGB 3) pledges JGB as collateral and get yen from the repo counterparty 4) at maturity of repo returns yen in exchange for the JGB 5) sells JGB and converts yen back into USD

Comment: Yes except there is no need to do any spot FX transactions. The exact steps depend on what clearing houses and settlement mechanisms are in place.  Crucial to understand there are no FX transactions.

Comment: For example you can purchase JGB and initiate repo for the Same settlement date, so the Yen flows net out.

Comment: Ok it would be interesting to know how you can buy a foreign asset without fx transactions in this case. Also because in a repo you usually borrow cash by pledging assets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repurchas

Comment: "For example you can purchase JGB and initiate repo for the Same settlement date, so the Yen flows net out", why would they net out?

Comment: For example if you do both transactions with Bank A, the payment instructions will cancel out leaving no net amount to be settled.  Banks only expect net amounts to be settled.

Comment: "Now assume that the agent decided to avoid the FX risk by keeping the cash in domestic currency and financing
the foreign security in the foreign repo market. That is, the agent finances the security at purchase by
immediately selling it while committing to buy it forward at an agreed price. (Here we abstract from the haircut so
that the security is altogether self-financing.) Current accounting principles require that this be reported on a gross
basis, so that the balance sheet doubles in size....

Comment: ... Yet the position is functionally equivalent to that of an FX swap or
forward. There is no FX risk, and the agent needs to finance the future obligation (debt) by coming up with the
corresponding foreign currency to settle the forward leg or to repurchase the foreign currency denominated asset. The only difference is that in case 3 the agent has the freedom to use the domestic currency cash to buy another domestic currency asset rather than having it tied up in a forward claim. "